# how RestClient gem work in ruby

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm using Rest-client gem in ruby.My code is as follows..,

```
require 'rest_client'

puts RestClient.get 'http://localhost:3000/articles'

puts RestClient.put 'http://localhost:3000/', {:params => {:Bat => 'ball'}}

RestClient.post 'http://localhost:3000/articles', {:params => {:Name => 'list1', 'Content' => 'Article1'}}
```

I refer the URL which runs in rails application, the user can can create, delete, edit,list the articles using the above url.For put,delete,post,get methods it produces the html code of the URL in my prompt.But it cannnot able to insert the post/delete an item from the list via ruby code.
It is possible in RestClient?

Comment: What error/response do you get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you need to be authenticated. You can do that with RestClient but you will need to chain your calls. See the rest_client Readme how to do that.

Comment: Low effort answer. The concept of chaining calls doesn't exist in the rest_client readme.

Comment: that answer was ok for the OP 4 years ago. Did you check the commit history for rest_client? Low effort questions deserve low effort answers. Sheesh.

Comment: If you had spent 2 more minutes typing out how to chain calls in rest_client, you would have taken this low effort question, and made it valuable. Instead you left me searching for information that doesn't exist in the readme.